# Read Rating From ITunes, write it to file

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-yosemite, itunes, id3

I have songs in iTunes on my MacBook pro that I have rated from one-start to five-star.  When I open the songs in my DJ software, it doesn't show the ratings because iTunes doesn't write them to the ID3 tag, but just keeps it within iTunes.

I have figured out that I can read the rating by doing this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set songRating to get rating of current track
end tell
return songRating
```

Also, I can get the location by doing this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set songLocation to get location of current track
end tell
return songLocation
```

How do now use the file path that I have to write the rating into the ID3 tag of the file?

Comment: Grab [mutagen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mutagen) (python module). It comes with `mid3v2`. Make a system call from the script to that program and use it to modify the `POPM` field, noting the [gotchas and inconsistencies](http://yabb.jriver.com/interact/index.php?topic=53283.0;wap2) with that field.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the comment tag to the rating, that should be readable in a 3rd party app.

e.g,

```
tell application "iTunes"

    set comment of the current track to "rating:" & (get rating of current track)

end tell
```

Ratings are percentage values, i.e, 2 stars == 40.